# Check all logins and logout to a localsystem in a network

Tags: c#, networking, logging, windows-services

Anyone can tell me what is the best way to get all logins/logouts to all systems by all accounts in a network?

1- use OnSessionChange event in windows service

OR

2- use api functions in windows service

I need the time and username of the account that logged in/logged out.

Comment: I wouldn't write code for this. Local Security Policy can be configured to audit logon events. These will then be stored automatically in the Security event log.

Comment: thanks, but i do not think the security event log can be useful for me, because it needs administrator privileges to read.

Comment: And you don't think "get all logins/logouts to all systems by all accounts in a network" is something that is properly limited to administrators?

Comment: I need login and logout times to calculate working times of users and show them if they want. The information in security event log on clients is not complete.To get my preferred information i should read security event log of server from clients that it does not allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done it successfully with using methods of ISensLogon2.